# Why can I not create a new record in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a new moderator:

### index.erb

```
<%= link_to 'add new user', new_admin_moderator_path %>
```

### Routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :moderator
  end
```

### moderator_controller.rb

```
 def new
   @moderator = Moderator.new
 end
 def create
   @moderator = Moderator.new(moderator_params)
   if @moderator.save
     redirect_to admin_moderator_index_url
   else
     render 'new'
   end
 end

 private
   def moderator_params
        params.require(:moderator).permit(:id, :fullname, :username, :password)
   end
```

### new.erb

```
<h1>Create new</h1>
<%= form_for [:admin , @moderator] do |u| %>
    <p>
        <%= u.lable :fullname %>
        <%= u.text_field :fullname %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= u.lable :username %>
        <%= u.text_field :username %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= u.lable :password %>
        <%= u.password_field :password %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <%= u.submit %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

It shows an error as below:

```
views/admin/moderator/new.erb where line #2 raised:
NoMethodError in Admin::Moderator#new
    undefined method `admin_moderators_path' for #<#<Class:0x607ce90>:0x907a0d0>
    Did you mean?  admin_moderator_path,
                   admin_moderator_index_path,
                   admin_moderator_url
Extracted source (around line #2):
<h1>Create new</h1> <%= form_for [:admin , @moderator] do |u| %> <p> <%= u.lable :fullname %> <%= u.text_field :fullname %> </p>
```

Comment: Where does it say that "admin_moderators_path" appear?

Comment: Can you please add routes in question ?

Comment: it showing: views/admin/moderator/new.erb where line #2 raised: 

Extracted source (around line #2):
<h1>Create new</h1>
<%= form_for [:admin , @moderator] do |u| %>
    <p>
        <%= u.lable :fullname %>
        <%= u.text_field :fullname %>
    </p>

Comment: Check the output of `rails routes | grep moderator#create` and update your form to `form_for @moderator, url: <path-from-previous-command> ...`

Comment: @HoklyLeng Please checkout my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line in your new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @moderator, url: 'path for your create action for moderator controller' do |u| %>
```

Comment: It showing error: views/admin/moderator/new.erb where line #2 raised.
when I use @moderator = Moderator.new  combine with form_for [:admin, @moderator] it have errors.

Comment: The error appears on the `form_for` and if you run `rake routes` you will find `admin_moderator_index_url` is a valid path

Comment: yes.....it work bro, but when I click submit it routes error.  
error message
No route matches [POST] "/admin/moderator/new"

Comment: which url you added in form ?

Comment: url: new_admin_moderator_path